# Is there a quicker way to make a Multi Page API Call?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm attempting to use an API provided by Coingecko. I know a website that uses to achieve what I'm trying to do but have no idea how they manage to do it. I want a list of all the coins with market data which takes a while as it's paginated and requires me to iterate over 40 pages. This website I'm referring to manages to have all the data within a few seconds of loading up. What am I missing? I attempted using Chrome Devtools to see what network calls were being made but couldn't see anything that would help.

Comment: The website you are referring to might have prefetched the data, and showing it using UI side pagination.

Comment: The data definitely appears to be there quite quickly. Are you saying there's a backend server that is fetching the data and serving it to the react frontend on page load?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the explanations. It's really hard to point out to the exact reason of this difference of behaviors with only this much information that you shared.

Comment: Well, here's the website. www.marketcapof.com. If you click the drop down box and search for coins you are able to find any of the 9000 coins available almost instantly. I know it must have fetched them somehow as it has all the info for the coin, such as image and latest price.

Answer (score 0):

By having a quick look on the website mentioned in the comment, I figured there are two kinds of calls they are making to **coingecko**:

1. https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=USD&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=false
2. https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&category=stablecoins&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=false

The first call returned 250 entries, and the second call returned 50 entries.

Now, if your application is not able to fetch these 250 entries from the first call, then something is wrong with your application. Although I can't say that your question follows the SO guidelines, but would be glad if this helps.

Comment: Yes, the first call retrieves 250, which is the first page. There are a total of 9000 coins, so you have to loop through roughly 40 pages to get them all. What I'm confused about is how the dropdown box allows me to find any of those 9000 coins when they've only fetched the first 250. It takes me a few minutes to fetch them all.

Comment: It is not searching over 9000 coins actually, it's searching through those 250 coins only. You can figure this out if you go all the way down of the dropdown, they have an option to extend the search giving a warning that it may cause some delay.

Comment: That's simply to populate the dropdown, but if you type the name of a coin outside the first 250 it instantly shows up which means it has already fetched the data for it.

Comment: @BrianE My bad, there was one more call which I missed: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list?include_platform=false , this is the one which is fetching a list of 9000 entries, you can use this API in your application and see if the response is what you want.